# Use label in assembly from C

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, nasm

I simply need a way to load the address of a label e.g. MyLabel: in e.g. 'src.asm' into a variable in e.g. 'src.c'. (These files will be linked together) I am using gcc and nasm to assemble these files. How can I load the label address?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two steps to this. First, you must export the label as global from the assembly file using the `global` directive.

```
global MyLabel

MyLabel: dd 1234    ; data or code, in whatever section.  It doesn't matter.
```

Next, you must declare the label as external in C. You can do this either in the code using it, or in a header.

```
// It doesn't matter, and can be plain void,
// but prefer giving it a C type that matches what you put there with asm
extern void MyLabel(void);            // The label is code, even if not actually a function
extern const uint32_t MyLabel[];      // The label is data
// *not*  extern long *MyLabel, unless the memory at MyLabel *holds* a pointer.
```

---

Finally, you get the address of the label in C the same way you get the address of any variable.

```
doSomethingWith( &MyLabel );
```

Note that some compilers add an underscore to the beginning of C variable and function names. For example, GCC does this on Mac OS X, but not Linux. I don't know about other platforms/compilers. To be on the safe side, you can add an `asm` statement to the variable declaration to tell GCC what the assembly name for the variable is.

```
extern uint8_t MyLabel asm("MyLabel");
```

Comment: I think this way is preferable (if it does what the questioner wants), since it simply makes the label visible at the linker level, and uses original C code to access it just like any other symbol.  No inline asm required.  (I have noticed the underscore mangling issue; would #ifdef checks be a nicer way of using the correct name?)

Comment: I think `void *` is possibly the most dangerous type you could give it (because it's so easy to forget the `&`).  The `char` type is often chosen for arbitrary symbols, but `void` should also work.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I took a bit to decide whether I should expand on choosing the type, but chose not to. I think a `char` would be just as easy to forget the `&`, since I don't usually look at the variable when I want its address. Forgetting it would also only make a difference in the amount of data read. Plain `void` would be better, but I didn't think you could do that (I could easily be wrong).

Comment: If it were `char`, at least you'd get a type error when you'd assign it (since you can't assign `char` to pointers), but with `void *` you can assign it to any pointer type without casting.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Good point, I didn't think of that. I don't really think its enough of a change for an edit though, so I just upvoted your comments for people to read.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: From testing, it appears that `clang` will give a warning for `&symbol` if `symbol` is declared as `extern void symbol;` -- not for the declaration, but because you can't take the address of an expression of type `void`.  This only happens with `-pedantic`, and I was not able to get GCC to give any warning or error messages no matter what flags I passed it.  (This is fairly tangential, however...)

Comment: This sounds great. I will try it when I get the time. (Hobby projects don't get a lot of time :))

Comment: I found something similar, and I ended up doing it as `extern void MyLabel();`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider an assembler "getter" routine.

Also, you might be able to simply fake the label to look like a routine to the C binder so that you could take the address of the "procedure".