# Unable to access correct global label data of assembly from C in linux

Tags: c, linux, assembly, embedded-linux

I have an assembly code (hello1.s) where global label **A_Td** is defined and I want to access all the long data values defined with global label **A_Td** from/inside C program.

```
.file   "hello1.s"
.globl  A_Td
.text
.align  64
A_Td:
    .long   1353184337,1353184337
    .long   1399144830,1399144830
    .long   3282310938,3282310938
    .long   2522752826,2522752826
    .long   3412831035,3412831035
    .long   4047871263,4047871263
    .long   2874735276,2874735276   
    .long   2466505547,2466505547
```

As **A_Td** is defined in text section, so it is placed in code section and only one copy is loaded into memory.

Using yasm , I have generated hello1.o file

```
yasm -p gas -f elf32 hello1.s
```

Now, to access all the long data using global label **A_Td** , I have written following C code (test_glob.c) taking clue from here [global label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045108/use-label-in-assembly-from-c).

```
//test_glob.c
extern A_Td ;

int main()
{
    long *p;
    int i;
    p=(long *)(&A_Td);
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        printf("p+%d %p %ld\n",i, p+i,*(p+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using following command I have compiled C program and then run the C code.

```
gcc hello1.o test_glob.c 
./a.out
```

I am getting following output

```
p+0 0x8048400 1353184337
p+1 0x8048404 1353184337
p+2 0x8048408 1399144830
p+3 0x804840c 1399144830  -----> correct till this place
p+4 0x8048410 -1012656358 -----> incorrect value retrieved from this place
p+5 0x8048414 -1012656358
p+6 0x8048418 -1772214470
p+7 0x804841c -1772214470
p+8 0x8048420 -882136261
p+9 0x8048424 -882136261
p+10 0x8048428 -247096033
p+11 0x804842c -247096033
p+12 0x8048430 -1420232020
p+13 0x8048434 -1420232020
p+14 0x8048438 -1828461749
p+15 0x804843c -1828461749
```

**ONLY first 4 long values are correctly accessed from C program. Why this is happening ?**

**What needs to be done inside C program to access the rest of data correctly ?**

I am using Linux. Any help to resolve this issue or any link will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @old_timer `extern long *A_Td;` won't work (and will probably crash horribly), but `extern long A_Td[];` should work (assuming C `long` is the same size as assembler `.long`).

Comment: right need a level of indirection in the asm.

Comment: I was thinking function label or single item you can use directly...forgot about address storage.

Comment: `extern A_Td ;` has an implicit type of `int`.  That's weird.  You should definitely use `extern long A_Td[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many bytes does "long" have in this system?

It seems to me that printf interprets the numbers as four byte signed integers, where the value `3282310938` has the hex value `C3A4171A`, which is above `7FFFFFFF` (in decimal: 2147483647) which is the largest four byte positive signed number, and hence a negative value `-1012656358`.
I assume that the assembler just interprets these four byte numbers as unsigned.

If you would use `%lu` instead of `%ld`, printf would interpret the numbers as unsigned, and should show what you expected.

Comment: @FrankPI, in my system sizeof(long) returns 4, means long takes 4bytes.

Comment: @bholanath: and what are the min and max values of a **signed** 32bit int?

Comment: @FrankPI, I got the right value printed as hex as you pointed out using %lx instead of %ld. Thank you for your prompt answer.

Comment: @FrankPI, yes use of %lu gives the correct output .

Comment: @bholanath: `.long` in x86 GAS assembly is *always* 32-bit, even when C `long` is 64-bit.  You happened to get lucky here, but you need to read the manual for your assembler.  e.g. https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Long.html says it's a synonym for `.int`, and the size and byte-order depends on the target.  `.quad` is 8 bytes.  Hmm, I can't actually find if/where it says that `.long` is 4 bytes for x86.  You'd think the i386 section would say, but it doesn't: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dDependent.html